# Choice of complex photon polarization vector

Tags: special-relativity, photons, polarization

Given a complex photon polarization vector, can I always choose a Lorentz frame and gauge in which it is real?

Comment: A similar question was asked here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178380/polarization-of-light-for-a-fast-moving-observer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and in fact you almost never can.$^{1}$   The full set of [$SO(3,1)$ Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group)—including both rotations and boosts, as well as combinations of the two—are, after all, completely real.  They act of vectors, such as polarization vectors (whether considered formally as unit three-vectors $\hat{\epsilon}$ or [four-vectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503605/how-can-we-interpret-the-components-of-a-polarization-four-vector) $\epsilon_{\mu}$) in an entirely real fashion, meaning (for the four-vector polarizations)
$$\epsilon_{\mu}'=\Lambda_{\mu}{}^{\nu}\epsilon_{\nu}\equiv\sum_{\nu\,=\,0}^{3}(\Lambda_{\mu}{}^{\nu})\epsilon_{\nu},$$
where each of the numbers $\Lambda_{\mu}{}^{\nu}$ is real. In fact, the $\Lambda_{\mu}{}^{\nu}$ are just the components of the Lorentz transformation matrix; this takes a form like
$$\Lambda=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\gamma & -\beta\gamma & 0 & 0 \\
-\beta\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right],
$$
corresponding in this case to a boost in the $x$-direction with velocity $v=\beta c$.

Physically, having a complex polarization vector (except in the case noted in footnote 1) corresponds to having an electromagnetic wave with a elliptical polarization.  A real polarization vector corresponds to a linear polarization, but for polarization along a given direction $\hat{k}$, there is only a one-dimensional space of linear polarizations, parameterized by the axis along which the elctric $\vec{E}$ oscillates perpendicular to $\hat{k}$.  (The fact that, for freely propagating electromagnetic waves, $\vec{E}\perp\hat{k}$, or equivalently $\vec{E}\cdot\hat{k}=0$, is a consequence of Gauss's Law $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}=0$ in vacuum.)

However, the full space of polarizations is two-dimensional, the [Stokes sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters).  For a given $\hat{k}$, any point on the Stokes sphere corresponds to a completely polarized wave, but only points on the equator are linearly polarized.  The north and south poles of the sphere represent perfect circular polarization, either right- or left-handed.  Moving down a meridian of the sphere, away from a pole, the polarization ellipse (the figure traced out by the vector $\vec{E}$ over one wavelength) becomes increasingly eccentric.  However, this kind of change to the polarization state cannot be achieved via a Lorentz boost.  The orientation of the polarization ellipse may be changed by boosting to a different Lorentz frame, but the overall degree of [ellipticity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178380/polarization-of-light-for-a-fast-moving-observer) cannot.  In other words, a $SO(3,1)$ transformation can move the apparent polarization state along a parallel of the Stokes sphere, but cannot change its latitude.

$^{1}$ The only time when it is possible to convert a complex polarization vector $\hat{\epsilon}$ in to a real one is if $\hat{\epsilon}$ is already just a real polarization vector times an overall phase.  For example, if $\hat{\epsilon}=i\hat{x}=(e^{i\pi/2})\hat{x}$, the complex nature of the polarization vector is illusory, and the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ phase may be absorbed into the propagating part of the wave.